# HTML/CSS/ Bootstrap - How to right aligne form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm totatally new in front-end technology. I try to write some code for my backend app. Now i'm using Html, Css and Bootstramp. I try to put searching form on the right side of my webpage. What i'm doing wrong.

page view:

[image]

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white;">Students Manager</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse-navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add 
student <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul> 
    <div class="pull-right">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="search" name="key" id="searchName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" 
placeholder="Search student....">  
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</nav>


//resto of code
```

css file:

```
body{
 margin-top:20px;
 background: #f5f5f5;
}
.card {
  border: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.w-60 {
  width: 60px;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.social-links li a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(89,206,181,.85);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
a {
  color: #707070;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions and understanding

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bootstrap's own grid system, you can position any element in the best way.

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in css

```css
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly it doesn't work